# repaint a frame in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint

I have written code for an online quiz. I would like to change questions by clicking "next" button, but repaint is not working; only new window is working. 
i can't even hide jftMainFrame since it works for 8 windows only.quest is a list containing questions and options ,its accessed from access db.repaint() is not working while i click the button.
i have 4 radiobuttons which displays the label.i want to repaint the label of radiobutton and also question
Please help me.

```
    JFrame jtfMainFrame, jtfMainFrame1;

    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Next question..");
            j++;
            quest = getCurrentQuestion();
            createWindow();
            validate();               
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please explain a little more - what do you mean by "not working". What do you want to happen? What actually happens? What exactly does `createWindow()` do? How are `j` and `quest` used? Can you show a bit more code?

Comment: j is counter,createWindow()is a built-in function which creates a new window.quest is a list which contains questions and options

Answer (score 1):

```
I would like to change questions by clicking "next" button,
```

I think that your question is about using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), rather than create lots of [Top-Level Comtainers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) on runtime

Answer (score 0):

Your question is definitely not clear.

What are you trying to do. If you are simply trying to "repaint/refresh" a panel or a component use paintImmediately();

for example

```
jMyPanel.paintImmediately(jMyPanel.getVisibleRect());
```

Hope it helps